How to plot a smooth decision boundary for a binary classifier using a neural network?
I am trying to implement a simple neural network to classify a circular dataset and plot a smooth decision boundary. However, my decision boundary is not smooth or incorrect. I want it to look like the boundary shown in this example:
like this 
When I run the code, the decision boundary is jagged, or it doesn’t match the shape of my dataset. I expect a smooth curve surrounding the inner class.
this is my code :
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles

# Generate dataset
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=100, noise=0.1, factor=0.3, random_state=0)
X = X.T  # Transpose X
y = y.reshape((1, y.shape[0]))  # Reshape y to row vector

# Visualization of the dataset
plt.scatter(X[0, :], X[1, :], c=y.flatten())
plt.title('Dataset')
plt.xlabel('Feature 1')
plt.ylabel('Feature 2')
plt.show()

def paramètres(n0=2, n1=2, n2=1):
    W1 = np.random.randn(n1, n0)
    b1 = np.zeros((n1, 1))
    W2 = np.random.randn(n2, n1)
    b2 = np.zeros((n2, 1))
    parametres = {
        'W1': W1,
        'b1': b1,
        'W2': W2,
        'b2': b2
    }
    return parametres

def G(X, theta, b):
    Z = theta.dot(X) + b
    return Z, 1/(1+np.exp(-Z))

def forwardPropagation(X, parametres):
    W1 = parametres['W1']
    b1 = parametres['b1']
    W2 = parametres['W2']
    b2 = parametres['b2']
    
    Z1, A1 = G(X, W1, b1)
    Z2, A2 = G(A1, W2, b2)  

    activations = {
        'A1': A1,
        'A2': A2
    }
    return activations

def backPropagation(X, y, parametres, activations):
    A1 = activations['A1']
    A2 = activations['A2']
    W2 = parametres['W2']

    m = y.shape[1]

    dZ2 = A2 - y
    dW2 = 1 / m * dZ2.dot(A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    dZ1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2) * A1 * (1 - A1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * dZ1.dot(X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    gradients = {
        'dW1': dW1,
        'db1': db1,
        'dW2': dW2,
        'db2': db2
    }
    
    return gradients

def update(gradients, parametres, learning_rate):
    W1 = parametres['W1']
    b1 = parametres['b1']
    W2 = parametres['W2']
    b2 = parametres['b2']

    dW1 = gradients['dW1']
    db1 = gradients['db1']
    dW2 = gradients['dW2']
    db2 = gradients['db2']
    
    W1 = W1 - learning_rate * dW1
    b1 = b1 - learning_rate * db1
    W2 = W2 - learning_rate * dW2
    b2 = b2 - learning_rate * db2

    parametres = {
        'W1': W1,
        'b1': b1,
        'W2': W2,
        'b2': b2
    }
    
    return parametres

def predict(X, parametres):
    activations = forwardPropagation(X, parametres)
    return activations['A2']

def neural_network(X, y, n1=2, learning_rate=0.1, n_iter=1000):
    n0 = X.shape[0] 
    n2 = y.shape[0] 
    np.random.seed(0)
    parametres = paramètres(n0, n1, n2)

    for i in range(n_iter):
        activations = forwardPropagation(X, parametres)
        gradients = backPropagation(X, y, parametres, activations)
        parametres = update(gradients, parametres, learning_rate)
    
    return parametres, activations

# Train the model
parametres, activations = neural_network(X, y, n1=2, learning_rate=0.1, n_iter=1000)

# Plot decision boundary
x_min, x_max = X[0, :].min() - 1, X[0, :].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[1, :].min() - 1, X[1, :].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.02),
                      np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.02))

Z = predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()].T, parametres)
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=[0, 0.5, 1], alpha=0.8, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)
plt.scatter(X[0, :], X[1, :], c=y.flatten(), cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)
plt.title('Decision Boundary')
plt.xlabel('Feature 1')
plt.ylabel('Feature 2')
plt.show()


Why exactly do you expect a smooth boundary? Please keep in mind that the fact that it is depicted as such in theory books does not make it such in reality.

I just need a smooth curve surrounding the inner class.

This does not answer the question, neither it justifies why the curve should be smooth indeed...
